# Facebook like button: predefined text in the popup window

Tags: facebook-like

I need to specify a predefined text in the textarea that pops up when you click "like". How can I do that? (I am not talking about the description that you can set with og:description).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that section of the post is populated with a [built-in like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-actions/likes/) (from your app). 
I don't think that there is a way to add text to a facebook like, unless the person who shares it wants to add a comment. If your app has special API privileges then you can probably add a personalized message. For that though, you have to apply and applications are closed at the moment. I hope this helps.